# chartjs rotate x axis labels to read from top to bottom

Tags: javascript, html, charts, chart.js

Here is the jsfiddle to my question: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/ye3usuhu/81/).
I want to rotate the x axis labels so as they read from top to bottom. But when the labels are longer, they get messed up.

```
overrideRotation: -12,
minRotation: -12,
maxRotation: -12
```

here is the messed up screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want to repeat "Month of" for every label, instead of setting the xAxes scaleLabel to "Month" and only writing the actual month for the label? Also, do you specifically want to use v1.0.1 of Chart.js because the library has been greatly improved in v2?

Comment: @TotZam actually this is a dummy example, my real names are even longer. So it is for the sake of example here.

Comment: @TotZam i prefer chart.JS version 2, i found this jsfiddle over the internet just to illustrate my problem.